# Moment.js and Typescript

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am trying to use moment.js with typepscript, however, when I try to create a new `moment`, I get the following message:

> TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature,
>   implicitly has 'any' type.

```
import * as Moment from 'moment';

const now = new Moment();
```

Should I be turning this into a class? And if so how? Thanks!

Comment: just use `const now = Moment();` or even better: `import * as moment from 'moment'` as it a function and not a class. which is generally spelled lowercase. and then you can use `const now = moment()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `new` with moment. Also, there's a couple different ways to do the import, depending on your typescript version and build config. You can read more about that in Moment's documentation here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/

Here's how it looks in my codebase (your import may be different):

```
import moment from 'moment';

const now = moment();
```

If you want to add an explicit type, it would be:

```
const now: moment.Moment = moment();
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's `import * as moment from 'moment'` at least that's what I use in my angular project. `import moment from 'moment'` throws an error. But you're right about that part that you should use the function without the new keyword.

Comment: Maybe my build setup is different. The codebase i'm in imports it the way i showed it. But i'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: That's weird though. May I ask if you installed it like: `npm i moment`?

Comment: package.json has the following entry: `"moment": "^2.22.2",`. Best guess as to what command was used to add it there would be `npm i --save moment`

Comment: Should be the same in this case... that's really weird. Nice addition with the type though +1

Answer (score 1):

Add `"noImplicitAny": false` in the `tsconfig.json` file of your typescript project. It will solve your problem.